# how to find a spline function from given control points

Tags: functions, spline

consider having an n-amount of control points in 2D space, what's the best way to find the function passing through the start and end points while approximating the path according to the other given control points? i would really appreciate it, if someone can give an example. thanks in advance

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and I'm not going to describe all of them. Can you be more explicit about what you want? Is it OK if the curve passes through the interior points, rather than approximating them? Do you care about the shape of the curve, or its mathematical form? What are you going to do with the curve after you have derived its equation?

Comment: Thanks bubba for your answer. what i would really like to do is to get a function of a bezier curve or a B-Spline just by giving any number of control points. i've read a lot about this subject but i would really like to have an exapmle so i can really understand it. So consider having 8 points: (2,3),(14,7),(33,16),(43,22),(51,31),(62,39),(78,42),(90,86), how would i get the function of the spline that would pass through the first and the last point? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "get the function". And you didn't answer my question about whether or not you want the curve to pass through all the points.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is Lagrange interpolation, which is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Suppose your points are $\mathbf{P}_i = (x_i, y_i)$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n$. You assign a parameter value $t_i$ to each point. Then you use Lagrange interpolation (twice) to interpolate the $(x_i,t_i)$ values and the $(y_i,t_i)$ values. A numerical example is given on the page I cited. This process will give you a parametric polynomial curve that passes through all the given points.

In the example you gave in your comment, the points have monotonically increasing $x$ values. Therefore, you can just construct a solution of the form $y = f(x)$, which is simpler than the approach I explained in the first paragraph above. The wikipedia page I cited tells you exactly how to do this using Lagrange polynomials, including a nice numerical example. I can't explain it any better than they did. This will give you a polynomial curve that passes through all the given points. A polynomial curve is a Bezier curve, so you have what you asked for.

If you don't want the curve to pass through the interior points (but only through the first and last ones), then you can use the given points as the coefficients of either a Bezier curve or a b-spline curve. [This page](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-construct.html) explains how.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you need is a constrained least square spline fitting with linear equality constraints. Forcing the start and end points becomes the first and last control poles of the spline are the linear equality constraints. You can use either a Bezier curve or a B-spline curve in the least square fitting, but using cubic B-spline curve is always a preferred approach.